# What's the ratio of horizontal to vertical velocity and travel distance for starship?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, spacex-super-heavy

As far as I understand the spacex starship trajectory is not exactly vertical, it looks more like the picture below.

If the height of the flight is 12.5km, then what is the horizontal distance it travels during that time? What is the max ratio between horizontal to vertical velocity while it descends? I couldn't find any more or less specific data about the flights.

[image: trajectory of spacex starship]

Comment: Are you talking about the SN-8 12.5 km hop? If so, then the picture is misleading because SN-8 did not land where it took off. [Here's an infographic about the SN-8 hop](https://www.reddit.com/r/SpaceXLounge/comments/k73ddk/spacexs_starship_sn8_test_flight/) I found on reddit. The trajectory was more parabolic in shape.

Comment: The launch and landing pad were at most 200 feet apart. In scale of 12.5 (40,000 feet) we can call it a rounding error.

Comment: The launch and landing pads are right at the beach (~800m), and in the downward looking camera from SpaceX's feed it looked like they started the belly flop just barely far enough off the coast that if the control scheme failed, it would impact the water. It would be interesting to know whether Ryan from Cosmic Perspective records the movement data from his robotic telescope mount, that would probably tell us a lot.